# To check whether there are words matching in a sentence with c# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a function that accepts 2 parameters.
Parameter 1: SearchTerm, 
Parameter 2: ProductName

How do I check whether the words in SearchTerm exists in ProductName, doesn't matter it occurs at the beginning, middle or end of ProductName?

It has to be word by word match, let say SearchTerm = "cano", ProductName = "canon", it should be return false, not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match only complete words you need [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, to add before and after your search term.

`\b` is a  zero width assertion that matches on a change from a word to a non-word character or from a non-word to a word character.

```
String term = "Foo";
String[] text = { "This contains Foo bar.", "Foo.", "Foobar", "BarFoo", "foo" };

Regex reg = new Regex(@"\b" + Regex.Escape(term) + @"\b");

foreach (var item in text) {
    Match word = reg.Match(item);
    if (word.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(item + ": valid");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine(item + ": invalid");
    }
}
```

Output:

> This contains Foo bar. => valid
>   Foo. => valid
>   Foobar => invalid
>   BarFoo => invalid
>   foo => invalid

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to be able to specify that it's a seperate word and not a sub-word, you'll need to use [regexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Your regex will probably look like this, if the word you're searching for is stored in the variable "lol":

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(lol + @"[^a-Z]"); // include grammar marks to avoid issues like "can." not matching
```

Essentially, you want to try to match just that word, and make sure that there's a character after it that isn't another letter. That way, you know it's not another word.

**Edit**: Try this beauty instead. Learned something myself.

```
 string sPattern = @"\b" + lol + @"\b";
```

[Here's some example usage.](http://pastebin.com/dAUeuPLt)

**Edit2**: Looks like stema got it first. [Here's the page I used, for reference.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Your solution has several issues. First it throws an Exception "Range in reverse order", because "Z" comes before "a", The other way round `[A-z]` would also be wrong because between "Z" and "a" there a 6 non letter characters in the ASCII table. The next issue is, it will fail if there is the string end after the search term and finally: What happens if there is something before the term in the text?

Comment: All excellent points. I'm obviously up a little too late for my own good. Let me see if I can fix that before I hit the hay.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need regex for simple string search.

```
ProductName.Contains(searchTerm);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Comment: However, he wants to avoid things like "can" being found in a sentence when "canon" is in that sentence. ".Contains" won't avoid this.